# calculate value based on current and previous row in cursor android

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I have a recycler adapter modified to use cursors set up and i am successfully returning results to a recyclerview via loader, etc. I am trying to display a calculation of a difference between the current record (displayed in the viewholder) and the previous record (may or may not be displayed on the UI based on the  position).

The query that currently fills the adapter displays transaction amounts by month.

Example. If the user selects a sort by month they would get the following. (They can also sort by spending amount.)

```
month   |  spending
--------+----------
12/2014 | 123
--------|----------
11/2014 | 145
--------|----------
10/2014 | 130
```

What is the best practice to display the following as the user scrolls through the recyclerviews. I would like the user to be able to select the type of sort and based on the results find the difference from the previous record.

```
month   |  spending | difference
--------+-----------+------------
12/2014 | 123       | + 22
--------|-----------+------------
11/2014 | 145       | + 15
--------|-----------+------------
10/2014 | 130       | null
```

The reason i want to use a cursor is because i only want to load results based on the position of the cursor. Is there a way i can rewrite the query so i can get the results i want without doing the calculation when the data is presented in the adapter?

**Option that currently works for me but i do not want to use:**

I have have gotten the results i want by using an using an array list and doing the calculations during the creation of an array list but im afraid as the user enters more data (ive tested with 1000 dummy records), eventually the user will have to wait for the list to be created and loaded to UI **every time the data set changes**.

Please help me understand the best practice when it comes to these scenarios.

Comment: if you don't want to calculate the whole thing at one time (load time) then maybe you can use a Custom Adapter to populate the list, then you can calculate the dif using the item at requested position and position-1 (if exist) at `getView()`

Comment: but in your case, it's position and position+1 [diff next to 12/2014 is spendingOf(11/2014)-spendingOf(12/2014)], right?

Comment: I forgot to mention that i am using recycler adapter modified to use a cursor. Yes you are correct in your assumption, but it will have to be position + 1 if user scroll up and position - 1 if user scrolls down because the views at the top are recycled as the they are gone from the UI. Because of this i think there has to be a better way. Such as rewriting the query to provide the desired result so i dont have to do the calculations in the adapter as the views are recycled.

Comment: no you dont have to detect which way scroll is going, it should be the same, in order to get the same results which is the correct result, no matter which way the scroll goes, try to do it in the getView() and don't forget to check (position+1) is not outOfIndex (data.size()>(position+1)) ...

Comment: Ok, after rethinking what you said, that makes sense. It is only position + 1, but what you said is easy to do if using an array list during the onBindViewHolder. I am unsure how to do so using a cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i thought of posting an answer of what i was telling you in the comments.
ope this helps you somehow.

- assuming you have a layout file `custom_row.xml` to represent each item in the list
- and in this layout you have 3 textviews, say txtDate, txtSpend and txtDif:
- your data list is an `ArrayList<SpendingItem>` where `SpendingItem` have (Date, Spend), and in the adapter class it's called `items`

then getView will look like:

```
@override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        //convertView == null or not, init ViewHolder, setTag or getTag (in case you are usin this approach to recycle views).

        //here comes the calculations:
        holder.txtDate.setText(items.get(position).getDate());
        holder.txtSpend.setText(items.get(position).getSpend() + "");//as getSpend() return int
        if(items.size() > position+1){
            holder.txtDif.setText((items.get(position+1).getSpend() - items.get(position).getSpend()) + "");
        //result is int, to avoid considering this int as a resource int (in strings xml file) or you can use Integer.toString()
        }else{
            holder.txtDif.setText("N/A");
        }

        // some other code ...

        return convertView;
}
```

**EDIT:**
using CusrsorAdapter:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View arg0, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    //here comes the calculations:
    holder.txtDate.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    holder.txtSpend.setText(cursor.getInt(2) + "");
    final int currentSpen = cursor.getInt(2); // conside index 2 is spending value in cursor
    if(cursor.moveToNext()){
        holder.txtDif.setText((cursor.getInt(2) - currentSpen) + "");
        cursor.moveToPrevious();//return to current position so you will not skip a row from cursor
    }else{
        holder.txtDif.setText("N/A");
    }

    // some other code ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wrote in my initial post that i have a working solution just as what you suggested above. I am asking for a solution via a cursor. So i dont have to reload an entire query result to an arraylist every time there is a change in the db as it takes a long time to load the adapter when there are 500 + records.

Comment: @user3300856 sorry did not understand this way, check updated answer, added a suggested sol using custom CusrsorAdapter

Comment: thanks i will try this and hopefully there are no performance issue when the user scrolls fast then i will reply back